# Handle errors for federated users password update in keycloak

Tags: keycloak

I am using keycloak custom user storage provider and users are getting from an external service.

The class implements the following interfaces:

```
public class CustomUserStorageProvider implements UserStorageProvider, UserLookupProvider, CredentialInputValidator, UserQueryProvider, CredentialInputUpdater {
```

When the user password is expired in isValid method the exception is catched and the requiredAction is added to prompt user to set a new password

```
UserModel userAdapter = loadedUsers.get(user.getUsername());
            if (userAdapter != null) {
                userAdapter.addRequiredAction(RequiredAction.UPDATE_PASSWORD);
                return true;
            }
```

The updateCredential method sends a request to an external service to update user password

```
   @Override
    public boolean updateCredential(RealmModel realm, UserModel user, CredentialInput input) {
        try {
            updateUserPassword(user.getUsername(), input.getChallengeResponse());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            log.error("Something went wrong", e);
        }
        return true;
    }
```

This works normally, updates the user password in an external service and authenticates user.

I need to display the according error message coming from an external service when something went wrong during the updating password e.g it doesn't meet the needs of the password policy(this is also defined in external service rather than in keycloak).

I researched but couldn't find a way how to do that.

Is there any way to achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if you have solved this but I faced the same problem and found this solution.
Just throw exception org.keycloak.models.ModelException and the error messages are propagated to the password change dialog.
Found this in the following code.
https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak/blob/main/services/src/main/java/org/keycloak/credential/PasswordCredentialProvider.java#L61

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I have the same issue. @user2836274 So, what you're suggesting is to make some logic changes directly to Keycloak and then use it for an external service?